# I have a Map into a Map javascript , how can I show them both with foreach(key,value)?

Tags: javascript, foreach, ecmascript-6, map-function

Hello I am trying show 2 maps the one is into the other, how can I do this with map.forEach()? For each sub I trying to show the predMap which has pred and obj.
I can show the sub but I cannot have the pred and obj. It shows [object Map] after the sub.

```
     function JSON_to_MAP(turtleMap, href, rel, val) {

              if (hyperCatRels[rel] != null) {
                sub = formatIDURI(href);
                pred = formatURI(hyperCatRels[rel].rdfRel);
                // check if val needs to be tranlated into RDF
                if (hyperCatVals[val] != null) {
                  val = hyperCatVals[val].rdfVal;
                }

                obj = hyperCatRels[rel].rdfValFunc(val);
                // predicate not in turtleMap
                if(turtleMap.get(sub) == null){
                    const objSet = new Set();
                    objSet.add(obj);
                    const predMap = new Map();
                    predMap.set(pred,objSet);    
                    turtleMap.set(sub,predMap);
                }
                // predicate already in turleMap
                else {
                  // predicate already exists
                  if(turtleMap.get(sub).get(pred) != null){
                    turtleMap.get(sub).get(pred).add(obj)
                  }
                  else { 
                    const objSet = new Set();
                    objSet.add(obj);
                    turtleMap.get(sub).set(pred,objSet);
                  }
                }
              }
            }

    turtleMap.forEach((key,value) => {
    console.log(value, key);
  });

  turtle_text += turtleMap.forEach((key, value) => {
    document.write(value + "<br />" + key + "<br />"); 
  });
```

[here is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChOhj.png)

Comment: Just nest the loops?

Comment: how can I do this?

Comment: You managed to nest if-elses, surely you can nest loops?

Comment: sorry for the late reply i found the solution turtleMap.forEach((turtlevalue, turtlekey, turtleMap) => {
    const predMap = turtlevalue; 
    document.write(turtlekey +"<br />");
    predMap.forEach((predvalue, predkey, predMap) => {
    document.write ("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + predkey + " :");
    const objSet = predvalue;
    objSet.forEach((value1, value2, objSet) => {
    document.write("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" + value1 + "<br/>");
    })
  })
 });